# need to get id from IEnumerable<item>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-core

So im trying to create a little website to help with my family's business.

I have two models, Jobs and Days.

```
public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int LotNum { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    public double PerHour { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}

public class Day
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int DayId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Hours { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public int Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

I need to make an Invoice, the invoice will be numbered. The days have the invoice number so ill be able to pick the days needed.
It would look something like this.

```
    Date LotNum Street      Suburb     Hours
    1/1/01 1 John Street Hurstville x hours
    1/1/01 1 John Street Hurstville x hours
    1/1/01 1 John Street Hurstville x hours
    1/1/01 1 John Street Hurstville x hours
```

I am able to get the days with the specific invoice number using this:

```
vm.Days = _dayRepo.GetAll().Where(d => d.Invoice == id);
```

By doing so i have the date and hours of that day but now i need to get the job information. Both Day and Job have the JobId so i would be able to link them but i just dont know how.

This is what i have so far:

```
public IActionResult Invoice(int id)
    {
        CreateInvoiceViewModel vm = new CreateInvoiceViewModel();
        vm.Days = _dayRepo.GetAll().Where(d => d.Invoice == id);
        //vm.JobId = 
        vm.Jobs = _jobRepo.GetAll();

        return View(vm);
    }
```

My view looks like this:

```
    @model CreateInvoiceViewModel


<table>

    @foreach (var item in Model.)

    {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Date.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yy")</td>
                <td>@item.Hours</td>


          </tr>
     }

</table>
```

I dont know what to put in for the foreach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What ORM are you use? Can you share your repository day class also?

Comment: Are invoices shared between jobs? It looks to me as if the invoice number should belong to the job entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need a join query. Define Your ViewModel like:

```
public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int LotNum { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string Suburb { get; set; }

    public double Hours { get; set; }
 }
```

Create a join query and convert it to ViewModel:

```
public IActionResult Invoice(int id)
{
    var query = from d in _dayRepo.GetAll()
                            join job in _jobRepo.GetAll() on d.JobId equals job.JobId
                            select new { Date=d.Date, LotNum= job.job , Street =job.Street , Suburb =job.Suburb , Hours =d.Hours };

    IEnumerable<InvoiceViewModel> viewModel = query.Select(c => new  InvoiceViewModel() 
   { 
     Date=query.Date,
     LotNum=query.LotNum,
     Street=query.Street,
     Suburb=query.Suburb,
     Hours=query.Hours 
   });

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what to do with that in my controller. Looks solid though!

Comment: @YanniAlevras you have to create a DataModel which includes your desired fields and convert this query to the model and change return type of `Invoice` controller to the model and bind it to your view

Comment: By DataModel you mean ViewModel?? I would greatly appreciate if you could show me a rough idea of what you mean in code somehow..

Comment: I had to change query.Date to c.Date and all the other ones because it wass giving me errors. My controller has no errors now but how am i suppose to call that in my view? i will show you how my view is

Comment: Actually dont worry, i was able to to convert it to my view by changing it up a bit, added another model called invoice and just added the query to it through the ViewModel. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should result in an IEnumerable with your ids

```
var ids = _dayRepo.GetAll().Where(d => d.Invoice == id).Select(x => x.JobId);
```

You can also add `.ToList()` to the end if you want it as a list.

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less how I would set it up, or at least the beginnings of how.

(I'm using EntityFrameworkCore and yes I understand that you are using repos at the moment)

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LotNum { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    public double PerHour { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Navigation Helper
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceJobRelationship> Invoices { get; set; }
}

public class Day
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Hours { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }

    // Navigation Helper
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceDayRelationship> Invoices { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation Helpers
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceJobRelationship> Jobs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceDayRelationship> Days { get; set; }
}
public class InvoiceDayRelationship
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    // Navigation Helper
    [ForeignKey("InvoiceId")]
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public int DayId { get; set; }
    // Navigation Helper
    [ForeignKey("DayId")]
    public Day Day { get; set; }
}
public class InvoiceJobRelationship
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    // Navigation Helper
    [ForeignKey("InvoiceId")]
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    // Navigation Helper
    [ForeignKey("JobId")]
    public Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your context

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<InvoiceDayRelationship>()
            .HasKey(id => new { id.DayId, id.InvoiceId });
        builder.Entity<InvoiceJobRelationship>()
            .HasKey(ij => new { ij.JobId, ij.InvoiceId });
    }

    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Day> Days { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InvoiceDayRelationship> InvoiceDays { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InvoiceJobRelationship> InvoiceJobs { get; set; }
```

Then you would be able to call pretty much anything you would like.

(Example Query)

```
    (from x in context.Invoices where x.Id == id select x).Include(inv => inv.Days).Include(inv => inv.Jobs);
```